# Unable to serialize VariableSpec(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.float32, alias_id=None) to JSON

Tags: python, json, tensorflow, serialization, neural-network

I am launching the following **neural network**, and I suspect that there is a mistake with some variables (especially in the *MeanShift* function) with the initialization of weights and biases.

```
################
##### RCAN #####
################

def RCAN(n_RCAB=3, n_RG=5, rgb_mean = [0.4488], rgb_std = 1, **kwargs):

    def _func(input_shape):
        import sys
        sys.setrecursionlimit(25000)

        # Start of the Model
        inputs = Input(input_shape)
        scaled_inputs = tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(255)(inputs)
        scaled_inputs = MeanShift(rgb_range=255, rgb_mean=rgb_mean, rgb_std=rgb_std)(inputs)


        # Head module
        x = Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same')(scaled_inputs)
        _inp = x

        # Body module
        for i in range(n_RG):
            x = ResidualGroup(x, n_RCAB)
        x = Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same')(x)

        add_global = tf.keras.layers.Add()([x, _inp])

        # Tail module
        x = UpSampling(add_global)
        x = Conv2D(1, 3, padding='same')(x)

        outputs = MeanShift(rgb_range=255, rgb_mean=rgb_mean, rgb_std=rgb_std, sign=1)(x)
        outputs = tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1.0 / 255)(outputs)

        # Defining the model
        model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
        return model
    return _func



######################
##### ABOUT RCAN #####
######################

def RCAB(x):
    _res = x

    x = Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same')(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU()(x)
    x = Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same')(x)

    x = ChannelAttention(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Add()([x, _res])
    return x

def ChannelAttention(x):
    _res = x

    avg_pool = tf.math.reduce_mean(x, axis=[1, 2, 3], keepdims=True)

    feat_mix = Conv2D(4, 1, padding='same', activation='relu')(avg_pool)
    feat_mix = Conv2D(64, 1, padding='same', activation='sigmoid')(feat_mix)

    multi = tf.keras.layers.Multiply()([feat_mix, _res])
    return multi

def ResidualGroup(x,  n_RCAB):
    skip_connection = x

    for i in range(n_RCAB):
        x = RCAB(x)

    x = Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same')(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Add()([x, skip_connection])
    return x

def MeanShift(rgb_range, rgb_mean, rgb_std, sign=-1):
    def _func(x):
        # Initilize weights
        weight_initer = tf.constant(value=1., dtype=tf.float32, shape=[1])
        W = tf.Variable(weight_initer, name="Weight", dtype=tf.float32)

        # Initilize bias
        bias_initer = tf.constant(value=[m * rgb_range * sign / rgb_std for m in rgb_mean], dtype=tf.float32)
        b = tf.Variable(bias_initer, name="Bias", dtype=tf.float32)

        x = Conv2D(1, 1, padding="same", kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.Constant(W), bias_initializer=keras.initializers.Constant(b), activation="relu")(x)
        return x

    return _func

def UpSampling(x, act=False):
    features = Conv2D(256, 3, padding='same')(x)
    high_res = tf.nn.depth_to_space(features, 2)

    if act:
        high_res = tf.keras.layers.ReLU(max_value=1)(high_res)

    return high_res
```

The error is **when saving the weights** (with checkpoints every 5 epochs), but the *update of any version (2.4 or 2.9) of tensorflow isn't working*.

> ValueError: Unable to serialize VariableSpec(shape=(1,),
> dtype=tf.float32, trainable=True, alias_id=None) to JSON, because the
> TypeSpec class <class
> 'tensorflow.python.ops.resource_variable_ops.VariableSpec'> has not
> been registered

Moreover, my inputs and target are percentile normalized. And I would like to know what layers or operations to add so that **predictions matches best the targets** (on the variables scaled_inputs and outputs of RCAN function for example).

I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**

Ok, found the problem: i think that kernel and bias were not trainable due to keras.initializers.Constant(W) (and same for b) in the Conv2D layer, or due to the tensorflow initializer (I was a bit lost because multiple ones exist). So I replaced it by: and it works

```
def MeanShift(rgb_range, rgb_mean, rgb_std, sign=-1):
    def _func(x):
        # Initilize weights and bias
        W = tf.keras.initializers.Constant(1.)
        b = tf.keras.initializers.Constant(rgb_mean[0] * rgb_range * sign / rgb_std)

        x = Conv2D(1, 1, padding="same", kernel_initializer=W, bias_initializer=b)(x)
        return x

    return _func
```